# Why did my flagging of a question become an automatic closure?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I wanted to flag a question, and indicate the reason I was flagging in that the question likely has the answer in a similar question (duplication).

But I didn't want to close it as a duplicate, just flag it as such. I know that closing questions as duplicates is sometimes disputed when the questions are not exact matches, but many times when the answer is "correct" it is done in this context.

Not wanting to get into a big debate about it, and simply wanting to make sure that this question would get attention and that judgement of it's duplicate status would go to review, I decided to flag it.

Much to my surprise, my flag turned into a closure.

Likely because I have a high rank in the Python tag. But I didn't want to close it.

[Python - Remove HTML-tag with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42206123/1561176)

Comment: You can't close flag once you can close vote.  You can only close vote.

Comment: You have a dupe hammer in the Python tag. Your dupe vote is *always* binding, there is no option to flag.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is this new?

Comment: Note that you should *always* vote as if you are the only one to vote. Stand by your votes; if you are not sure, make it a comment and leave it to others to actually vote.

Comment: @InbarRose It's the behavior I have observed ever since being here (couple years now).  The dupe hammer might be new to you but the flags should have been votes for you starting at 3K rep.

Comment: Good news: you can also re-open it with a single vote. If you didn't want to close, just reopen.

Comment: Okay, well it seems silly that I have the option to flag then.

Comment: Anyway, I have reopened the question. And will make my thoughts a comment.

Comment: @InbarRose you can flag to moderator attention or as rude, offensive, spam.

Comment: @InbarRose The ability to flag for closure is there because not every has the privilege to vote to close.